# How to do quarter in python dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I've a dataframe df1:

```
     Date     Number
0 Jan-2017       20
1 Sep-2021       30
2 Jul-2021       40
3 Mar-2017       50
4 Apr-2020       60
5 Jun-2020       70
6 Feb-2017       80
```

'Date' column is in datatype of 'object'

I need to group the 'Date' in quarter like

```
1st quater -->(Jan,Feb,Mar)
2nd quater -->(Apr,May,Jun)
3rd quater -->(Jul,Aug,Sep)
4th quater -->(Oct,Nov,Dec)
```

Sum the 'Number' column

Expected Output like this:

```
     Date     Number
0 Q1-2017       150
1 Q3-2021        70
2 Q2-2020       130
```

**Thank You For Your Time :)**

Answer (score 4):

You can  also, try this:

```
df.groupby(pd.to_datetime(df['Date'], format='%b-%Y').dt.to_period('Q'))['Number'].sum()
```

Output:

```
Date
2017Q1    150
2020Q2    130
2021Q3     70
Freq: Q-DEC, Name: Number, dtype: int64
```

Answer (score 2):

The groupby can be done using the datetime attributes (make sure your `Date` column is datetime, i.e. `df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])`):

```
>>> df.groupby([df['Date'].dt.quarter, df['Date'].dt.year]).sum()
           Number
Date Date        
2017 1        150
2020 2        130
2021 3         70
```

Just a matter of renaming the index then.  You could achieve the format you specified by:

```
df = df.groupby([df['Date'].dt.quarter, df['Date'].dt.year]).sum()
df.index = df.index.set_names(['Quarter', 'Year'])
q = df.index.get_level_values('Quarter').astype(str)
y = df.index.get_level_values('Year').astype(str)
df.index = 'Q'+ q + '-' + y
```

Giving:

```
         Number
Q1-2017     150
Q2-2020     130
Q3-2021      70
```

Answer (score 1):

#### Use [`.resample()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.resample.html) + [`.sum()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.resample.Resampler.sum.html) + [`.query()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.query.html):

```
df_out = (df.assign(Date=pd.to_datetime(df['Date'], format='%b-%Y'))
            .resample('Q', on='Date', kind='period')
            .sum()
            .query('Number != 0')
         ).reset_index()
```

**Result:**

```
print(df_out)

     Date  Number
0  2017Q1     150
1  2020Q2     130
2  2021Q3      70
```